Trying to convert Offset type to LatLng for GoogleMap in Flutter
I have points drawn on the screen, their position is based on Offset and I'm trying to convert this Offset to responding LatLng on googleMap.
Do you have idea if it is event possible to do? I need this, because I'm trying to add drawing polygons with touch gesture.
I tried to use this function from GoogleMapController:
Future<LatLng> getLatLng(ScreenCoordinate screenCoordinate) { return GoogleMapsFlutterPlatform.instance .getLatLng(screenCoordinate, mapId: mapId); }
but it seems ScreenCoordinate are coordinates of the whole map and it doesn't fit with Offset.

Can you show example values for Offset and LatLng?

"but it seems ScreenCoordinate are coordinates of the whole map and it doesn't fit with Offset" - what do you see if you print(controller.getLatLng(ScreenCoordinate(0, 0)))?

@psink controller.getLatLng(ScreenCoordinate(0, 0)) seems to be center of whole map, I have locked map on
static const wroclawSouthWest = LatLng(51.060645, 16.899128);
static const wroclawNorthEast = LatLng(51.154198, 17.205372);
with CameraTargetBounds(LatLngBounds(
northeast: wroclawNorthEast,
southwest: wroclawSouthWest,
))
and what you are asking for is: LatLng(51.111628759030445, 17.061292827129364)

@DhafinRayhan LatLng is locked on values as I said above, and Offset is (0,0) left top corner of mobile screen and right down corner is something like (800, 400) (I assume it depends of size of mobile screen).

from what the docs say it should be something like this: Offset offset = ....;  final latlng = controller.getLatLng(ScreenCoordinate(offset.dx, offset.dy))
